# The namespace '<global namespace>' already contains a definition for 'Handler"

Tags: c#, asp.net

This HTml Code

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Capctha Image with Refresh Button</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function RefreshCaptcha() {
            var img = document.getElementById("imgcaptcha");
            img.src = "Handler.ashx?query=" + Math.random();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <img src="Handler.ashx" id="imgcaptcha" />
    <a href="#" onclick="javascript:RefreshCaptcha();">Refresh</a>
    </form>
</body>
</html>>
```

Captcha.aspx.cs

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

public class Handler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        using (Bitmap b = new Bitmap(200, 50, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
        {
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b))
            {
                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 150, 40);
                g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, rect);

                //Creating String Draw
                Random r = new Random();
                int StartIndex = r.Next(1, 5);
                int Length = r.Next(5, 15);
                string DrawString = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "0").Substring(StartIndex, Length);


                //Creating Fount and Bursh
                Font drawFont = new Font("Arial", 16, FontStyle.Italic | FontStyle.Strikeout);

                using (SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue))
                {
                    // Create point for upper-left corner of drawing.
                    PointF pointdraw = new PointF(10, 15);
                    // Draw string to screen.
                    g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Blue, 0), rect);
                    g.DrawString(DrawString, drawFont, drawBrush, pointdraw);
                }

                b.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
                context.Response.End();
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    }
```

I am Getting Erros The namespace '' already contains a definition for 'Handler" like this how Can solve it  and Give any idea about error
and i am adding handler.ashx

Comment: Add a namespace to your classes.

Comment: @haim770 thanks for Reply i  added  this  namespaces 
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

Comment: @haim770 adding class namespace but not working

Answer (score 0):

Do you get this error upon compile-time or run-time?

This error usually occurs at compile-time and suggests that there is another Page/Handler/UserControl/ServerControl with the class-name `Handler`.

Also looking at your structure, things are really wired:

- `Captcha.aspx` holds HTML code (but, I do believe so, points via directive to `Captcha.aspx.cs`)
- `Captcha.aspx.cs` holds the class `Handler` (which implements `System.Web.IHttpHandler` but rather should be a `System.Web.UI.Page`)

Summing it up: I believe there's a flaw with the referencing. The content of `Captcha.aspx.cs` is wrong and possibly a duplicate of a `Handler.ashx.cs`-file ...